# Memory Read Error while accessing pointers in object

Tags: c++

I have subdivided my question into different sections for better understanding. They are as below:

### A) Classes My Question is related to

I have a class TLst representing list as below:

```
template <class TVal>
class TLst{
public:
  typedef TLstNd<TVal>* PLstNd;
private:
  int Nds;
  PLstNd FirstNd;
  PLstNd LastNd;
public:
  TLst(): Nds(0), FirstNd(NULL), LastNd(NULL){}
  TLst(const TLst&);
  ~TLst(){Clr();}
  explicit TLst(TSIn& SIn);
  void Save(TSOut& SOut) const;

**TLst <TVal>& operator = (const TLst <TVal> &t)
  {
    TLst<TVal>::PLstNd Nd;
    if (Len()!=t.Len()) { Clr(); }
    for (TLst<TVal>::PLstNd np = t.First(); np!=NULL ; np=np->Next()) {
        Nd = AddBack(np->GetVal()); 
    }
    return *this;
  }**

  void Clr(){
    PLstNd Nd=FirstNd;
    while (Nd!=NULL){PLstNd NextNd=Nd->NextNd; delete Nd; Nd=NextNd;}
    Nds=0; FirstNd=NULL; LastNd=NULL;}

  bool Empty() const {return Nds==0;}
  int Len() const {return Nds;}
  PLstNd First() const {return FirstNd;}
  PLstNd Last() const {return LastNd;}

**PLstNd AddBack(const TVal& Val){
    PLstNd Nd=new TLstNd<TVal>(LastNd, NULL, Val);
    if (LastNd!=NULL){LastNd->NextNd=Nd; LastNd=Nd;}
    else {FirstNd=Nd; LastNd=Nd;}
    Nds++; return Nd;
  }**

  PLstNd AddFrontSorted(const TVal& Val, const bool& Asc=true);
  PLstNd AddBackSorted(const TVal& Val, const bool& Asc=true);
  void PutFront(const PLstNd& Nd);
  void PutBack(const PLstNd& Nd);
  PLstNd Ins(const PLstNd& Nd, const TVal& Val);
  void Del(const TVal& Val);
  void Del(const PLstNd& Nd);

  PLstNd SearchForw(const TVal& Val);
  PLstNd SearchBack(const TVal& Val);

  friend class TLstNd<TVal>;
};
```

Similarly I have the class TLstNd to represent a list-node as below:

```
template <class TVal>
class TLstNd{
public:
  TLstNd* PrevNd;
  TLstNd* NextNd;
  TVal Val;
public:
  TLstNd(): PrevNd(NULL), NextNd(NULL), Val(){}
  TLstNd(const TLstNd&);
  **TLstNd(TLstNd* _PrevNd, TLstNd* _NextNd, const TVal& _Val):
    PrevNd(_PrevNd), NextNd(_NextNd), Val(_Val){}**

  TLstNd& operator=(const TLstNd&);

  TLstNd* Prev() const {Assert(this!=NULL); return PrevNd;}
  TLstNd* Next() const {Assert(this!=NULL); return NextNd;}
  TVal& GetVal(){Assert(this!=NULL); return Val;}
};
```

And I have the members and constructors of class TVec (not the entire class) as shown below

```
template <class TVal>
class TVec{
public:
  typedef TVal* TIter;
protected:
  int MxVals; // if MxVals==-1, then ValT is not owned by us, we don't free it!
  int Vals;
  TVal* ValT;
  void Resize(const int& _MxVals=-1);
  TStr GetXOutOfBoundsErrMsg(const int& ValN) const;
public:
  TVec(): MxVals(0), Vals(0), ValT(NULL){}
  TVec(const TVec& Vec);
  **explicit TVec(const int& _Vals){
    IAssert(0<=_Vals); MxVals=Vals=_Vals;
    if (_Vals==0){ValT=NULL;} else {ValT=new TVal[_Vals];}}**
  TVec(const int& _MxVals, const int& _Vals){
    IAssert((0<=_Vals)&&(_Vals<=_MxVals)); MxVals=_MxVals; Vals=_Vals;
    if (_MxVals==0){ValT=NULL;} else {ValT=new TVal[_MxVals];}}
  explicit TVec(TVal *_ValT, const int& _Vals):
    MxVals(-1), Vals(_Vals), ValT(_ValT){}

...

};
```

And I have the class TPair as below:

```
class TPair{
public:
  TVal1 Val1;
  TVal2 Val2;
public:
  TPair(): Val1(), Val2(){}
  TPair(const TPair& Pair): Val1(Pair.Val1), Val2(Pair.Val2){}
  **TPair(const TVal1& _Val1, const TVal2& _Val2): Val1(_Val1), Val2(_Val2){}**
...
  TPair& operator=(const TPair& Pair){
    if (this!=&Pair){Val1=Pair.Val1; Val2=Pair.Val2;} return *this;}
  bool operator==(const TPair& Pair) const {
    return (Val1==Pair.Val1)&&(Val2==Pair.Val2);}
...
};
```

### B) What I am doing?

a) I have a TVec>> class "typedef"-ed as

```
typedef TVec<TPair<TInt, TLst<TInt>>> TNdClass;
```

b) Next, I create an object of TNdClass, as

```
TNdClass UsrClassList(MXCLASS_SIZE); //calls TVec(const int& _Vals)
```

If you see the TVec constructor which is bold, the above call sets Vals, MxVals and allocates MxVals memory for ValT which means UsrClassList allocates memory of size MXCLASS_SIZE*sizeof(TPair>).

c) Next, I am assigning Val1 (of type TInt) and Val2 (of type TLst) to two variables NdCnt (of type TInt) and Nodes (of type TLst). And declare a variable NdClss of type TPair> as below:

```
TInt NdCnt(0);
TLst<TInt> Nodes;
NdCnt = UsrClassList[VecIdx].Val1; //assigning TInt to TInt
Nodes = UsrClassList[VecIdx].Val2; //assigning TLst<TInt> to TLst<TInt>
TPair<TInt, TLst<TInt> > NdClss; //declaration
```

d) Next I am adding a TInt of value 1 to Nodes using the AddBack function of TLst (see above in bold) and assign a TPair object instantiated with NdCnt and Nodes to NdClassas below:

```
Nodes->AddBack(1); //adding a TInt of value 1 to Nodes
```

e) Finally I am creating a new object of type TPair with NdCnt and Nodes values as parameter and is assigning to NdClss variable (type TPair) declared in step c).

```
NdClss = TPair<TInt, TLst<TInt>>(NdCnt, Nodes);
```

This step ends up with an exception with memory read error.

Further down the code, when I am debugging the values of Nodes.First()->NextNd or Nodes.First()->PrevNd the compiler gives "memory read error" which I feel indicates that the NextNd and PrevNd pointers are not allocated with memory.

When I debug the code, I get the value '???' for the watch variables PrevNd and NextNd:

```
-       FirstNd 0x00e6b830 {PrevNd=0x00000000 NextNd=0x00000000 Val={...} } TLstNd<TInt> *
+       PrevNd  0x00000000 {PrevNd=??? NextNd=??? Val={...} }   TLstNd<TInt> *
+       NextNd  0x00000000 {PrevNd=??? NextNd=??? Val={...} }   TLstNd<TInt> *
+       Val {Val=0 Mn=-2147483648 Mx=2147483647 ...}    TInt
-       LastNd  0x00e6b830 {PrevNd=0x00000000 NextNd=0x00000000 Val={...} } TLstNd<TInt> *
+       PrevNd  0x00000000 {PrevNd=??? NextNd=??? Val={...} }   TLstNd<TInt> *
+       NextNd  0x00000000 {PrevNd=??? NextNd=??? Val={...} }   TLstNd<TInt> *
+       Val {Val=0 Mn=-2147483648 Mx=2147483647 ...}    TInt
```

Any suggestions of why the memory for Nodes.First()->NextNd and Nodes.First()->PrevNd are not allocated? And what I need to do to allocate the memory of those two pointers in TLst class?

Look forward to replies.

Somnath

Comment: That is the most hideous coding style I have ever seen. What, you hate vowels or something?

Comment: I am new to C++. Have just started coding for 1 month and still learning it.

Comment: You need to fix the space bar on your keyboard or start using it.  Also, don't abbreviate; abbreviations do not significantly reduce development time but may extend it due to reduced readability.  Also, don't prefix class names with 'C', it causes problems (See any Microsoft MFC code).

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer. But my eyes are bleeding right now after reading your question...

For your first question :

I do not see in your code the allocation of TLstNd::PrevNd and TLstNd::NextNd.

And you are saying that you are having a memory read error after accessing to these members...

May be you should allocate them...

For your second question :

Use the keyword *new* to allocate objects...

Comment: But where to allocate them? All the classes I mentioned are in a library which I guess is not meant to be changed. I was looking to know at what line I am missing my memory allocation.

Comment: Ok, if it is a library... You have to pass previously allocated object to the contrcutor TLstNd::TLstNd() which takes a prev and a next

Comment: But I am calling the TLstNd constructor from the constructor of TLst which itself is defined in the library. And I can't change the TLst constructor

Comment: You could allocate them from a bank, a public garden, or an object pool.  Objects are allocated before they are used.  For example, an object is allocated before it is inserted into a linked list.